# For a disconnected graph, is there a word for the maximum order of a component?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, definition

The *order* of a graph is the total number of vertices it contains.
Suppose you have a disconnected graph, then each group of connected vertices is a *component*.
We can consider the order of each component as if it were its own connected graph.
I am interested in the maximum order among the components, is there a word for this?

Comment: I don't think so. I usually hear it referred to as "the order of the largest component".  In context, if you have defined the components as C_1, ... C_k, ordered from largest to smallest, then you could simply write |C_1|. But I don't know of a word for it on its own